# wordpress get post id from side widget

Tags: wordpress, widget

I am trying to get the post id from a widget I am putting into the sidebar, but what ever I try I seem to get random post id's from other posts.

I have tried:

```
            $id = get_the_id();

            $post_id = $GLOBALS['post']->ID;

            global $wp_query;

            $thePostID = $wp_query->post->ID;
```

The template I am using is classipress and I am putting my widget into the sidebar they provide. They already have a form at the top of the sidebar which uses the post id. They use

```
            global $post;
```

I have tried this also and it too gives my a different post id, but not the correct one.

I am all out of ideas at this stage.

Comment: What does the widget do and what do you need to do with the post ID once you get the value? If there are other loops on the same template (or within the widget), then that could interfere and mess up your values.

Comment: I am really trying to get the category (taxonomy) of the post the user is viewing to show other related posts in that category. Easy to do at the bottom of the post itself but I need it in the sidebar which is not as straight forward for some reason. Iread something about being outside the loop and I am seeing the last record in the loop and not the post id I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your plugin is added with:

```
add_action("widgets_init", "your_init");
```

otherwise `$post` won't be initialized at the time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand - why would the widget in the sidebar have a dedicated post ID? As far as I'm aware, post ID's are saved for actual posts (or pages, even) and not elements like widgets? Could the reason you're not getting the "correct" ID be because there isn't one? How do you know what the "correct id" is in the first place?

Comment: I am trying to get the id of the post that the user is currently looking at. I really want to get the category the post is in to show more posts in. It has to be n the side bar. I can do it at the bottom of the post with no trouble, but for this website to work right I have to have it in the sidebar.